# How to include date range in SQL query for Data Studio BigQuery community connector

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I'm trying to make a community connector using the advanced services from Google's Data Studio to connect to my BigQuery data table.  The connector is all set up and my getData function returns a query which looks like:

```
var sqlString = "SELECT * FROM `PROJECT.DATASET.TABLE` WHERE " +
"DATE(timestamp) >= @startDate AND DATE(timestamp) <= @endDate;"
```

where PROJECT, DATASET, and TABLE are filled in with their respective IDs.  The 'timestamp' field is a BigQuery field in my data table of type TIMESTAMP.

In my getConfig function, I'm setting the configuration to add a daterange object to the request passed into getData:

```
function getConfig() {
  ...
  config.setDateRangeRequired(true);
  ...
}
```

I'm then returning the community connector object (defined as 'cc' variable in code below) in my getData function, setting the sql string, query parameters for startDate and endDate, and some other necessary info:

```
function getData(request) {
  ...
  return cc
    .newBigQueryConfig()
    .setAccessToken(accessToken) // defined earlier
    .setBillingProjectId(billingProjectId) // defined earlier
    .setUseStandardSql(true)
    .setQuery(sqlString)
    .addQueryParameter('startDate', bqTypes.STRING, 
  request.dateRange.startDate)
    .addQueryParameter('endDate', bqTypes.STRING, 
  request.dateRange.endDate)
}
```

When I run this connector in a report, it connects to BigQuery and even queries the table, but it does not return any data.  When I replace @startDate and @endDate with string literals of format 'yyyy-mm-dd', it works as expected, so it seems like my only problem is that I can't figure out how to set the date range parameters in the query (which I assume I'm supposed to do to allow date range control in data studio reports).  How do I configure this daterange object so that people can control daterange tags in data studio reports?

Edit: For clarification, I know how to add the date range control on a report.  The problem is that the query does not return any data even when the date range query parameters are passed in.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up fixing my SQL query.  I made my WHERE condition as

```
WHERE DATE(requestTimestamp) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

and it actually returned data correctly.  I didn't mention another parameter I was using in my query because I thought it was irrelevant, but I had quotes around another conditioned parameter, which may have screwed up the query.  The condition before was more like:

```
WHERE id = '@id' AND DATE(requestTimestamp) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

I think putting quotes around @id was the problem, because changing the query to:

```
WHERE id = @id AND DATE(requestTimestamp) BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

worked perfectly

Comment: Correct. Putting quotes around @id was the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a **Date range control** and configured the timestamp field to it. It should automatically pick the timestamp type field.

Go to `Insert` and select `Date range control` to add it to your report.

[image]

You can select the date range in view mode.

[image]

Like this,

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your response.  I'm asking how to configure the date range control in the getData function of the connector.  As you can see, I already configured date range control in getConfig.  What do you mean by "configure the timestamp field to it"?  do I need to include the date range in my SQL query?

Comment: I have added a few screenshots if that helps you. But you should be able to filter the data from the source itself too. I can do a filter query to CloudSQL.

Comment: I'm aware of how the date range control works on the front end of the data studio report.  My problem is that my query is not returning any data, even when I set the date range control on the report. For example, if I manually add constant dates like '2020-08-23' to my query instead of startDate and endDate, then it works perfectly.  But when I pass in the date parameters, it does not work...